# changing font size and font of a custom message added after comment

Tags: customization, filters, comments, comment-form, fonts

hi i have added a code in function file of the theme to show a default custom message after the user leaves a comment of the blogposts . it reads like this .

```
add_filter('after_comment_text', 'add_custom_content');
function add_custom_content( $comment_text, $comment ) {
        if ($comment_text) {
                $comment_text .= "<div class='wpd-custom-text'>the comment added here is by the author and my website doesn't have any take on this .. </div>";
        }
        return $comment_text;
}
```

i would like to change the font size and font (may be in indices) of the custom message i added ie the comment added here is by the author and my website doesn't have any take on this ..what should i change in this code to attain the same 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS, either in a separate CSS file like this:

```
.wpd-custom-text{
  color: #f44242;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

or inline like this:

```
<div class='wpd-custom-text' style="color:#f44242; font-family: 'Arial', 'Helvetica', sans-serif; font-size: 15px; font-weight: 900;">the comment added here is by the author and my website doesn't have any take on this .. </div>
```

Depending on the web fonts available to your site, just change the font-family, font-size and font-weight values.